# Why does LLVM ARC repeatedly retain objects before throwing them?

Tags: objective-c, exception, automatic-ref-counting

Consider the following simple functions:

```
void simple_throw(id object) {
    @throw object;
}

void extra_throw(id object) {
    id tmp0 = object;
    id tmp1 = tmp0;
    id tmp2 = tmp1;
    @throw tmp2;
}
```

I initially thought that both of these functions should compile to the same assembly, and both should be equivalent to just calling `objc_exception_throw(object)` (since [function arguments are `autorelease` by default in ARC](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters)), perhaps with a single `objc_retain(object)` added (since [ARC isn't exception safe](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions) and defaults to leaking).

But this isn't the case. Here is the assembly (removing some of the extra fluff and `.cfi_*` directives; clang arguments: `-fobjc-arc -Ofast -fomit-frame-pointer -S`):

```
_simple_throw:
    pushq   %rax
    callq   *_objc_retain@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _objc_retainAutorelease
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _objc_exception_throw

_extra_throw:
    pushq   %rbx
    movq    _objc_retain@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rbx
    callq   *%rbx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   *%rbx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   *%rbx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   *%rbx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _objc_retainAutorelease
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _objc_exception_throw
```

`simple_throw` retains `object` *twice*, and `extra_throw` retains `object` 5 times!

This leads to two questions:

1. What is the optimal assembly (in terms of retains and autoreleases) for `simple_throw` that the compiler should be generating (assuming we want the generated code to be ARC-compatible)?
2. Why do the assignments to local variables in `extra_throw` result in extra retains? I'm inclined to think this is a compiler bug.

Comment: For what it's worth, it does the same if your replace the `@throw` statements with calls to a `noreturn` function. Does seem buggy.

Comment: I think it would normally add the corresponding release calls at the end of the scope of the local/parameter variables and an optimization pass would remove redundant pairs. The no-return statements prevent the "natural" end of the scope from being reached, so those are just dropped and the retains can't be optimized away.

Comment: That seems very plausible!